# construct DAX formula: average time spend on a postal code during delivery

Tags: mysql, datatable, powerbi, dax

I have a table that contains information about delivery dates, times, city and postal code and PCgroup. Delivery dates are ranged from Tuesday to Friday included (so 4 days), and all this for an entire month (so 4 weeks in total, or 16 days). The structure is as follows:

`Table_1`

```
Postal code | PCgroup| City | Delivery Time | Delivery Date | Delivery Tour ...
  14000     | 14000  | Caen |   10:00:00    |   12.11.2023  |    500        ...
  14000     | 14000  | Caen |   10:25:02    |   12.11.2023  |    500        ...  
  14001     | 14000  | Caen |   10:27:00    |   12.11.2023  |    500        ... 
  14001     | 14000  | Caen |   10:28:00    |   13.11.2023  |    500        ... 
  14001     | 14000  | Caen |   10:32:00    |   13.11.2023  |    500        ...
  14200     | 14200  | HSC  |   10:24:02    |   13.11.2023  |    500        ...
  14203     | 14200  | HSC  |   10:31:15    |   13.11.2023  |    500        ...
```

Some more info about the data:

- Date format is: DD.MM.YYYY
- Let's take *Delivery Date* 12.11.2023 :
- Every *PCgroup* will have a starting *Delivery Time* (for instance for chosen *Delivery Date* and *PCgroup*=14000 the starting *Delivery Time* is 10:00:00, so the first delivery for the chosen date and for this *PCgroup* starts at 10:00:00)
- The same *PCgroup* has an ending *Delivery Time* as well (for instance, still for chosen *Delivery Date*=12.11.2023 and *PCgroup*=14000, the ending *Delivery Time* is 10:27:00 , so the last delivery for the chosen date and for this *PCgroup* is made at 10:27:00)

`I'm looking to create a measure or another table that will give average time spent for a chosen *PCgroup*.`

`The logic and conditions behind the dax formula that I want to make are the following:`

- for every line that contains the same *PCgroup* in the table (for instance there are 3 lines that have PCgroup=14000)
- **MinAVGvalue**: get the average of all starting Delivery Times (in the example table for *PCgroup*=14000, it will be the average of 10:00:00, 10:28:00). I suppose that I could extract the first occurance of *Delivery Time* for every *PCgroup* and every new *Delivery Date* (there will be [16 days to consider * number *PCgroups*] to extract and to get their average) to obtain the Min Values and after that I will have to find their average to get the **MinAVGvalue**.
- **MaxAVGvalue**: get the average of all ending Delivery Times (in the example table for *PCgroup*=14000, it will be the average of 10:27:00 and 10:32:00). I suppose that I could extract the last occurance of *Delivery Time* for every *PCgroup* and every new *Delivery Date* (there will be [16 days to consider * number *PCgroups*] to extract and to get their average) to obtain the Max Values and after that I will have to find their average to get the **MaxAVGvalue**.
- at this point I will have the *MaxAVGvalue* and the *MinAVGvalue* for each *PCgroup*. Now I should do *MaxAVGvalue* - *MinAVGvalue* to get the **AvgTimePerPCgroup**

`====================================`

- However somehow I also need to consider 2 following problems:

1. I need to **account for pauses between Delivery Times** (brakes, changing driver or else). So if, for a chosen *Delivery Date* and *PCgroup* there is a gap between *Delivery Times* that is greater than 30min (Let's say for *Delivery Date*=14.11.2023 and *PCgroup*=14000 one line shows *Delivery Time*=12:00:00 and the line that follows shows *Delivery Time*=14:00:00 which is more that 30min gap), I will have to substract this gap from the *AvgTimePerPCgroup* of this *PCgroup*. Moreoever, I would like to add some sort of a prefix or a letter to the *AvgTimePerPCgroup* that had minutes substracted from them.
   (So I could quickly identify where there was a gap and to look for causes).
2. Also, sometimes for a single *PCgroup* there could be **multiple Delivery Tours**. It occurs when more than 1 vehicle does the delivery. In this case, I'll need to identify *PCgroup* that have more than 1 *Delivery Tour* and I need to consider them separately. So each *Delivery Tour* should have its own *AvgTimePerPCgroup*.

`For now, I have managed to construct the following formulas:`

```
MaxAVGvalue = 
FORMAT ( CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table_1'[Delivery Time]), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table_1', 'Table_1'[PCgroup] ) ),"hh:mm" )

MinAVGvalue = 
FORMAT ( CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table_1'[Delivery Time]), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table_1', 'Table_1'[PCgroup] ) ),"hh:mm" )
```

> but I couldnt find a way to account for pauses and multiple delivery
> tours, also the formula picks only the single most eary delivery hour
> for each PCgroup and the single most late delivery hour for each
> PCgroup.

```
AvgTimePerPCgroup = (([MaxAVGvalue] - [MinAVGvalue])*24)
'which gives a decimal number that I can later convert and format
```

`Could you please help me constructing the dax formula(or maybe a table via a query) and point on problems in my logic of how I would proceed, if there are?`

Here is agoogle sheet with data sample: [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gcEWwKyaTlKnJdAchzCKXTjiJAJV9VhxT_JGnmzr_Ng/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you encounter? Please provide sample data, covering your two "problems", and the expected output. Dates should be formatted as yyyy-mm-dd, otherwise anyone wanting to mock your scenario will have to reformat the data.

Comment: There are some inaccuracies I think. The first 3 rows of data refer to a pc group on 12.11.2023 so the max time of that group is 10:27:00 (not 10:28:00 wich is on the next day). Also later you ask for averages but refer to them as MIN or MAX, I assume these are typos?

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell thank you, I've corrected the inaccuracies :)

Comment: @user1191247 I've edited the post and added a sample data in a google sheet. Dates have the format states in the post, I have a huge database with this format, why the format I have isn't suitable?
Today I will post the formula I made so far, but I'm stuck with my limited knowledge on how to even tackle the two problems..

Comment: "The ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD (2023-12-21) is intended to harmonize these formats and ensure accuracy in all situations" (wikipedia)  it is the best format for international use, and this site is international. As long as it is clear that you use some other format we can deal with it. But many in the USA forget that most folk in the world (approx 90%) don't know that 3/7/2023  is a march date, or conversely that folks in the USA would comprehend 12/1/2923 as a Jan date.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell Thank you, I've added note about the date format